# Linking verbs and be verbs

Tags: verbs, infinitives

Is this grammatically correct, and is the infinitive phrase functioning as a predicate nominative?

> The tree grew to envelop the whole yard.

My reasoning is that I am using the past tense form of the linking verb 'grow'. 
Thanks for any help

Comment: Yes, it is fine. The infinitival clause "to envelop the whole yard" is a **complement** of the verb "grew".

Comment: Is there terminology to distinguish that complement from the one in *He shuddered to think what could have happened.* ?

Comment: An infinitival clause following "shudder" falls towards the boundary between adjunct and complement. If the former, it would be an adjunct of cause. Otherwise a catenative complement, like the one in the OP's example.

Comment: Can "to envelop the whole yard" be considered an 'adjunct of result|effect' ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm just going to blatantly steal BillJ's comment above.

Yes, the sentence is fine as written. The infinitival clause "to envelop the whole yard" is a **catenative complement** of the verb "grew".

However a similar infinitival clause following "shudder", as in the sentence:

> He shuddered to think what could have happened.

would be classified somewhere between an **adjunct** and a **complement**.